# Empty video_insight response from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page access token and I'm trying to retrieve the video_insight of my page's videos in the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

The endpoint is returning fine for my first 4 videos and the remaining 2 videos I'm receiving an empty data response.

```
{
    "data": [
    ]
}
```

I'm using the same token for all my requests. I have the read_insights permission.

Does anyone know what's causing the empty response?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @Rami I don't remember what was the issue exactly but I think in my case they were videos managed by a page owned by a different account, so I had to use a different access token or something.